# Domain Attribute Invalid - Set Cookies

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, cookies, session-cookies

I have built a basic demo backend using nodejs and ui using reactjs. When I login in using credentials, I am trying to set cookies. But it says some things like this "**this. set-cookie domain attribute was invalid with regards to the current host URL**". I have deployed both backend and ui on to Heroku separately. All network request is working fine. But the only issue I am facing is set-cookies not getting updated says domain attribute was invalid. Can anyone please guide me or suggest me where I am going wrong

Ui Doamin URL - https://visitplanui.herokuapp.com/

Node end point what i configured is something mentioned below

```js
 return res.
 cookie("auth",token,{domain: "visitplanui.herokuapp.com",path: "/"}).status(200).
 send ({code:  200,status: "Account details found & authenticated",})
```

FYI please find the below screenshots

.[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hey @nagendra-n, were you able to solve your problem? If yes, could you please share your solution?

Answer (score 4):

Heroku does not allow the installation of third-party cookies in its domain [application name] .herokuapp.com in accordance with the server’s response. Only if you set cookies via js can you change them. To set third-party cookies, you need to add your own domain, which you can purchase through any domain registration service.
Pay attantion while registration nw domain, company that maintains the DNS servers that translate a custom domain name to a destination ('DNS Target’). The fields are often called CNAME, ALIAS, ANAME, or A records. Only the first three work with Heroku apps, as A records require an IP address and Heroku apps do not have stable inbound IP addresses.

Comment: Can you point to Heroku documentation where they state they don't allow the installation of third-party cookies in Heroku domain? I don't quite get your explanation, so I would like to read more.

Answer (score 0):

Alexandr's answer seems to be on point. You cannot set cookies on herokuapp.com due to reasons mentioned [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/cookies-and-herokuapp-com)

So the best option is to buy a domain and then try to set it there.
Check out the link for better understanding.